# Past perfect without Past tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, perfect-aspect

> As a technology visionary, Elon Musk has created cars that have
> challenged the conventional automobile industry and rockets that have
> saved space transportation costs.

Is this sentence correct? It appears to have multiple past perfects with no past tense. Given that there are no connected events here, I'm tempted to correct this with all past tense

As a technology visionary, Elon Musk created cars that challenged the conventional automobile industry and rockets that saved space transportation costs

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is present perfect, not past perfect.

present perfect- have/has + past participle

past perfect- had + past participle

We can use the present perfect to give new information. But we usually use the simple past tense if we continue to talk about it.

As a technology visionary, Elon Musk **has created** cars that **challenged** the conventional automobile industry and rockets that **saved** space transportation costs.

Comment: Thanks! So if the sentence that follows says ‘Now, he aspires to connect the world using starlink….’ , then will that count as new information? In that case is the usage of present perfect in the original sentence appropriate?

Comment: I find nothing odd with the present perfect in the original sentence. It says that the challenging and saving continue to be relevant to the present, though the precise meaning of that "relevance" is not spelt out.